# Friend Computer doesn't work, others do

Tags: firefox

A friend of mine is currently having problems and I do not know the solution. His first issue is that his Firefox would display "Connection was reset" or would not show at all, while Internet Explorer would work, but it has issues such as freezing or crashing when going to Google.

His second issue is he says that any online game he plays will freeze and crash, which is related his internet issues. But his issue continues as his offline games will also freeze and crash after about 4 minutes, and they were working fine beforehand.

His father's computer who is also within the same network works fine, as he is able to go on Firefox and non of the following problems arises.

I am uncertain what is the problem and I've been googling around to find it, but nothing really matches.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Could be a few things...

- **Bad network drivers** - check the vendors site to ensure he is using the **latest** updated network driver for his card. (This is my best guess, since a bad network driver would cause network problems but could also cause the crashing you are explaining due to the low level drivers operate at.)
- **Overheating problems** - Check his temperatures with something like [speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php).
- **Bad memory** - give [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) a run to verify all the sticks are fine.

Comment: Might I also add a possibly defective motherboard. It happens...

Answer (score 1):

> His first issue is that his firefox
>   would display "Connection was reset"
>   or would not show at all, while
>   Internet Explorer would work, but it
>   has issues such as freezing or
>   crashing when going to google.

Is it because of a proxy thing? Maybe you can verify that the proxy for both IE and Firefox are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Some antivirus scans could also be useful.

Google for ["antivirus online scan"](http://www.google.fr/#hl=en&source=hp&q=%22antivirus+online+scan%22&btnG=Google+Search&fp=bef2bbdfae36c311) and use a couple of the best-known to scan his computer (each takes some hours to complete). Some that I like are [Trend Micro House Call](http://housecall.trendmicro.com/) and [Kaspersky Labs Free Virus Scan](http://www.kaspersky.com/virusscanner). Please note that they might require you to use Internet Explorer as your browser

Also some anti-adware software scans would be useful, such as: [ad-aware](http://www.lavasoft.fr/) and [spybot](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/home/index.html).

Comment: don't use 'google for' as an answer, provide solutions and/or links.

Comment: There are quite a few of them to chose, among the first goggle answers, and I prefer not to impose my personal preferences. In any case, the google result will be still correct some years in the future, but my pointers may not be.

Comment: You might be right - I've edited my answer.

Comment: Bear in mind that some sites advertising themselves for online antivirus scans might be embedding malware.  (I'm sure you've all seen the popups claiming you have viruses or registry problems.)  Therefore, just Googling for "antivirus online scan" might be a really bad idea.

Comment: Google ranking gives some (unintentional) protection.

Answer (score 0):

connection being reset might be a bad dns server as well. Try using a third party one and see if it helps. 4.2.2.x is good